# Maximum of two terms of two different sequences. Need help.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let $a_n, b_n$ be two sequences such that $a_0, b_0 >0$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n + \frac{1}{2b_n} , b_{n+1}=b_n + \frac{1}{2a_n} \forall n\ge 0$. 
Prove that $$max(a_{2018},b_{2018}) \gt 44?$$

I tried this sum and the furthest I could go was that I got an expression $$\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} = \frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}$$. How should I proceed with this or maybe if my approach is wrong , How should I approach these kind of sums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c_n$ denote $a_n+b_n$.  Then
$$c_{n+1}=a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{2a_n}+b_n+\frac{1}{2b_n}=c_n\left(1+\frac{1}{2a_nb_n}\right).$$
By AM-GM, $$a_nb_n\leq \left(\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}\right)^2=\frac{c_n^2}{4}.$$
This implies
$$c_{n+1}\geq c_n\left(1+\frac{1}{c_n^2/2}\right)=c_n+\frac{2}{c_n}.$$
Therefore
$$c_{n+1}^2\geq c_n^2+4+\frac{4}{c_n^2}>c_n^2+4.$$
Consequently
$$c_n^2>c_0^2+4n>4n$$
by induction.  Therefore, $c_n>2\sqrt{n}$.  This proves that $a_n>\sqrt{n}$ or $b_n>\sqrt{n}$.  In particular since $\sqrt{2018}>44$, we get $a_{2018}>44$ or $b_{2018}>44$.

Comment: Very elegant solution!! Thanks